# How to check status of Spark applications from the command line?

Tags: apache-spark

To check running applications in Apache spark, one can check them from the web interface on the URL:

`http://<master>:8080`

My question how we can check running applications from terminal, is there any command that returns applications status?

Answer (score 21):

If it's for Spark Standalone or Apache Mesos cluster managers, [@sb0709's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37420931/1305344) is the way to follow.

For YARN, you should use [yarn application](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YarnCommands.html#application) command:

```
$ yarn application -help
usage: application
 -appStates <States>             Works with -list to filter applications
                                 based on input comma-separated list of
                                 application states. The valid application
                                 state can be one of the following:
                                 ALL,NEW,NEW_SAVING,SUBMITTED,ACCEPTED,RUN
                                 NING,FINISHED,FAILED,KILLED
 -appTypes <Types>               Works with -list to filter applications
                                 based on input comma-separated list of
                                 application types.
 -help                           Displays help for all commands.
 -kill <Application ID>          Kills the application.
 -list                           List applications. Supports optional use
                                 of -appTypes to filter applications based
                                 on application type, and -appStates to
                                 filter applications based on application
                                 state.
 -movetoqueue <Application ID>   Moves the application to a different
                                 queue.
 -queue <Queue Name>             Works with the movetoqueue command to
                                 specify which queue to move an
                                 application to.
 -status <Application ID>        Prints the status of the application.
```

Comment: Master , i am using shell script for spark-submit , how to get Application ID  from it ?

Comment: run yarn application -list then check Application-Id column

Answer (score 10):

You can use `spark-submit --status` (as described in [Mastering Apache Spark 2.0](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-submit.html#status)).

```
spark-submit --status [submission ID]
```

See the [code of spark-submit](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmitArguments.scala#L277) for reference:

```
if (!master.startsWith("spark://") && !master.startsWith("mesos://")) {
  SparkSubmit.printErrorAndExit(
    "Requesting submission statuses is only supported in standalone or Mesos mode!")
}
```

Comment: Note that (according the the link) the `--status` option only works for Spark standalone or Mesos with cluster deploy mode (not YARN)

Comment: when setting the `--master` argument the port of the listener is the same used when submitting the application? (say 7077)

Answer (score 3):

I have found that it is possible to use REST API to submit, kill and get status of Spark jobs. The REST API is exposed on master on port 6066.

1. To create the job, use the following curl command:

   ```
   curl -X POST http://spark-cluster-ip:6066/v1/submissions/create 
      --header "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8"
      --data 
       '{
           "action" : "CreateSubmissionRequest",
           "appArgs" : [ "blah" ],
           "appResource" : "path-to-jar-file",
           "clientSparkVersion" : "2.2.0",
           "environmentVariables" : { "SPARK_ENV_LOADED" : "1" },
           "mainClass" : "app-class",
           "sparkProperties" : { 
               "spark.jars" : "path-to-jar-file",
               "spark.driver.supervise" : "false",
               "spark.app.name" : "app-name",
               "spark.submit.deployMode" : "cluster",
               "spark.master" : "spark://spark-master-ip:6066" 
            }
        }'
   ```

   The response includes success or failure of the above operation and submissionId

   ```
   {
      'submissionId': 'driver-20170829014216-0001',
      'serverSparkVersion': '2.2.0',
      'success': True,
      'message': 'Driver successfully submitted as driver-20170829014216-0001',
      'action': 'CreateSubmissionResponse'
   }
   ```
2. To delete the job, use the submissionId obtained above:

   ```
    curl -X POST http://spark-cluster-ip:6066/v1/submissions/kill/driver-driver-20170829014216-0001
   ```

   The response again contains success/failure status:

   ```
   {
        'success': True,
        'message': 'Kill request for driver-20170829014216-0001 submitted',
        'action': 'KillSubmissionResponse',
        'serverSparkVersion': '2.2.0',
        'submissionId': 'driver-20170829014216-0001'
   }
   ```
3. To get the status, use the following command:

   ```
   curl http://spark-cluster-ip:6066/v1/submissions/status/driver-20170829014216-0001
   ```

   The response includes driver state -- current status of the app:

   ```
   {
     "action" : "SubmissionStatusResponse",
     "driverState" : "RUNNING",
     "serverSparkVersion" : "2.2.0",
     "submissionId" : "driver-20170829203736-0004",
     "success" : true,
     "workerHostPort" : "10.32.1.18:38317",
     "workerId" : "worker-20170829013941-10.32.1.18-38317"
   }
   ```

I found out about REST API [here](http://arturmkrtchyan.com/apache-spark-hidden-rest-api).

Answer (score 2):

As in my case, my spark application runs on Amazon's AWS EMR remotely. So I make use of Lynx command line browser to access the spark application's status.
While you have submitted your spark job from one terminal, open another terminal and fire the following command from new terminal.

```
   **lynx http://localhost:<4043 or other spark job port>**
```