# Is there a shell-command for spark that says what jobs are queued or running?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

Environment:  Spark 1.6.2; Linux 2.6.x (Red Hat 4.4.x); Hadoop 2.4.x.

I launched a job this morning through `spark-submit` but do not see the files it was supposed to write.  I've read a bit about the web UI for monitoring spark jobs, but at this point, my only visibility into what is happening on the Hadoop cluster and HDFS is through a bash-shell terminal.

Question:  what are the standard ways from the command-line to get a quick readout on spark jobs, and any log trail they might leave behind (during or after job execution)?

Thanks.

Comment: If you know the application ID, have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37420537/how-to-check-status-of-spark-applications-from-the-command-line

Comment: On which master are you running your job ? If it's on yarn, you can try : yarn logs -applicationId <you_application_id>

Comment: We're on `yarn`.  If my job prints the `SparkContext.applicationId`, then `yarn` will tell me a lot about that job.  But my question is more general:  is there a shell-command that lists *all* jobs queued or running?  If you're from a *nix background, the equivalent command would be `ps`.

Comment: May be yarn application -list ?

Comment: @DrissNejjar -- thx, I'll give you credit if you post your response as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `yarn application -list`